# MSBuild _CopyWebApplication not copying <link> from vbproj

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, msbuild, build-automation

We have a CMD file which loads an MSBuild XML file and builds and publishes our VB .NET Web App. I noticed today that one of the user controls we're using is not being copied to the UserControls folder in the output directory. However when I build and publish the project from within Visual Studio 2008 that file is there.

I believe the reason this is happening is because the file that is in the UserControls folder in the project is a shortcut to a file in a different solution within the same project. The ItemGroup XML in the `MyProject.vbproj` file looks like this:

```
<Content Include="..\OtherSolution\UserControlFile.ascx">
  <Link>UserControls\UserControlFile.ascx</Link>
</Content>
```

In the MSBuild.xml file we have, the following is being run after the solution has been built:

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectRootPath)\MyProject.vbproj" 
            Targets="_CopyWebApplication;_BuiltWebOutputGroupOutput" 
            Properties="OutDir=$(BuildFilesPath)\" />
```

Does anyone have any idea why the shortcut is not being copied to the `OutDir`? I've checked a bunch of questions on here, and tried Google, but there doesn't seem to be solutions specific to this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use a number of linked files in our projects, the only way we can get them to work is to set the 'Copy to Output Directory' property to 'Copy Always'

Comment: It's been so long since I posted this I totally forgot about it. This works. This is how we fixed the issue. Thanks for the answer.